# Changes all values in dictionary and not just the corresponding one

Tags: python, file, dictionary, for-loop

I've been stuck on this for an hour and don't know what it could be. It has to be something stupid.

I have a file which contains data of a some balances of accounts:

```
currency:CZK amount:10000 available:3000 priceUSD:500
currency:EUR amount:500   available:100  priceUSD:600
currency:GBP amount:1000  available:800  priceUSD:1400
```

And here I try to read the file - I have a dictionary called dp to store the data in every line of the fine. Than I want to add it to a dictionary called d with the currency as a key.

```
d, dp = {}, {}
with open('balances.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        pairs = line.split()
        currency = pairs.pop(0).split(':')[1]
        for p in pairs:
            ls = p.split(':')
            key = ls[0]
            value = ls[1]
            dp[key] = value
        d[currency] = dp
```

But instead of my desired output:

```
{'CZK': {'amount': '10000', 'available': '3000', 'priceUSD': '500'},
 'EUR': {'amount': '500', 'available': '100', 'priceUSD': '600'},
 'GBP': {'amount': '1000', 'available': '800', 'priceUSD': '1400'}}
```

I get:

```
{'CZK': {'amount': '1000', 'available': '800', 'priceUSD': '1400'},
 'EUR': {'amount': '1000', 'available': '800', 'priceUSD': '1400'},
 'GBP': {'amount': '1000', 'available': '800', 'priceUSD': '1400'}}
```

If I run the debugger and watch values of the dictionaries the dp always changes all the values in d and not just the one with corresponding key.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a new `dp` dict in your inner `for` loop and not reuse it.  What's happening is that you are assigning references to the single "global" `dp` as the value(s) in your `d`.  You don't want that, obviously.

You can also just change the last line to:

```
d[currency] = dict(dp)
```

That will have the same effect of creating a new `dict` for each key in `d`

Comment: Oh yeah - that makes sense. Thank you!